# DB2 Trigger Loop through all fields/column in a row

Tags: db2, database-trigger, db2-luw

I'm trying to create a trigger which will loop through all columns in the changed row, compare them to each other, and then insert a row into a transaction history for each column that changed (where `NEW.column != OLD.column`).

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. I've found plenty about using cursors for rows, but not for using them for columns.

I have something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADD_AUDIT_HISTORY AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON MY_TABLE
  REFERENCING OLD AS o
              NEW AS n
  FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
  BEGIN
    # LOOP THROUGH COLUMNS
      IF newColumnValue != oldColumnValue THEN
        INSERT INTO AUDIT_HISTORY (columnName, oldValue, newValue) VALUES (columnName newColumnValue, oldColumnValue)
    # /LOOP THROUGH COLUMNS
  END;
```

The trigger needs to work on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` so I know I may need to do some juggling of which one I pull the columns off of as well.

Comment: Rethink your idea/concept - that would be a huge overhead - check out Db2 Replication solutions which fit far better to what you want to do (or what you described)

Comment: The problem is, at this point, we don't have access to go higher up. I'm in a large company and need to work with what we have access to at the moment. It would be nice if we could use smarter tools, but it's not an option at this point. Luckily, this is an internal app which only services a couple dozen users at most, so it's not as big of an impact as you might thing.

Comment: Which Db2-platform and version ? Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows?

Comment: Linux/Unix/Windows, added the appropriate tag.

Comment: Db2 replication is part of a Db2 license so no extra costs - depending on the replication technology used. Another great option is to use temporal tables - using system temporal tables the old version of a row is kept in a history table.

Comment: What is the business driver, for what purpose is transaction-history needed. For LUW, the amount of work required to setup SQLreplication, or even the db2audit functionality, is potentially less than the maintenance overhead of triggers (which won't fire for LOAD if that is ever used).  At worst, you should consider *not* working out what changed inside of triggers, but simply log the new row columns for insert/update, and *let the reporting* work out what has changed, and for delete log the PK. But as @MichaelTiefenbacher explains, this is just a poor solution, likely throwaway.